# Draw a rectangle over CIImage class in objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos

I wanted to load a image as `CIImage` and draw a rectangle on a specific region of that image and save the result image into a directory. Please help me.

Comment: Why do you want to do this as a `CIImage`?

Comment: I am working on Mac OS application, so I found that I can load a image using CIImage. Thata why, Anyway, How do I do that

Comment: I think you're extremely mistaken. `CIImage` is for working with `CoreImage`. It does image processing, but it's not the right tool to simply load an image, draw something on top of it, and save the image back out again. On the desktop you'll probably want to use `NSImage`, on iOS you'll want `UIImage`, or in both places you could drop down to CoreGraphics and use `CGImage`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Will you be able to provide an example. (objective-C code or a link). Thanks again

Comment: If it's OSX, this might work (didn't try): http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/60108-drawing-into-an-nsimage.html